# How to monitor events on an Solidity Smart Contract using hardhat and ethers?

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, hardhat, events

I'd like to monitor events happening on-chain on a specific Smart Contract. I'd like to know every time a `Transfer` event happens. I tried to write a code with hardhat, but no events if being logged. Here is my code:

```js
  const abi = [
    "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed id)"
  ]

  const MyContract = await new hre.ethers.Contract(
    "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
    abi,
    hre.ethers.provider
  )

  MyContract.on("Transfer", (from, to, id) => {
    console.log("Transfered:", from, to, id)
  })
  console.log("monitoring...")
```

I know that there are events occurring in the blockchain, but my code is not tracking them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you cannot pass in the event name directly on the watcher function in ethers.js. Please refer the docs for more info: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--events

Answer (score 0):

```
filter = {
    address: "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
    topics: [
        utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")
    ]
}
provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {
    // Emitted whenever a token transfer occurs
})
```

Try updating the function like this and you'll be able to monitor the transfer events provided the provider emit such events.

Answer (score 0):

[Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) have some great tools for monitoring, and these all come with a free account for limited testing purposes.

If you want to simply monitor transactions, for instance, their SDK allows a `eth_getTransactions` call, where you can, for example, specify a `to` address.

There are **plenty** of tutorials online depending on what you're looking to achieve.

If you come unstuck at some point, post your question and tag me - I'll do what I can to help :D